# Validation of result before executing the query

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

When running a stored procedure to fetch some rows, First I want to validate if the query will return a row before sending the result, and second if it is possible to validate without running the same query twice.

I am using a cursor to store the yielded result, So I tried the cursor attribute `%ROWCOUNT` & `%NOTFOUND`. But the doesnt quite work. Plus I want to do this without running a loop on the cursor.

```
procedure MODULE_LIST_GK(p_module_Id IN MODULE_LIST.MODULE_ID% TYPE,
                                     p_Error_Code     out nvarchar2,
                                     p_Error_Msg      out nvarchar2,
                                     p_Cursor         out sys_refcursor)   IS
 BEGIN
    OPEN p_Cursor FOR
       SELECT A.MODULE_ID,
         A.MODULE_NM,
         A.AUTH_STATUS_ID
         FROM MODULE_LIST A
         WHERE A.MODULE_ID=p_module_Id;

       SELECT COUNT(MODULE_ID)
       INTO v_row_num
        FROM MODULE_LIST A
        WHERE A.MODULE_ID=p_module_Id;

       IF v_row_num=0 THEN
         p_Error_Code := SQLCODE;
         p_Error_Msg := 'Does not Exists';
         Return;
       end IF;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        p_error_code:= SQLCODE;
        p_error_msg := SQLERRM;
  END MODULE_LIST_GK;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation have several points that could be improved.

**First** if you expect that for lot of parameters the returned cursor will be empty,
than **first check the empty cursor** and only after this check open the cursor. You do it vice versa.

How to check if the cursor is empty? Unfortunatelly you must fetch the first row to be able to verify it.

```
 open l_cur for
   select id, status from tab where id = p_id; 
 fetch l_cur into l_id, l_status;
 if l_cur%NOTFOUND then
    p_Error_Msg := 'Does not Exists';
    Return;
 end if;
```

This check is far more effective that the often used `count(*)` as it is considering only the first (few) rows and not counting **all rows** in the cursor.

If the check fails you are ready, othervise simple open the cursor and return it.

```
 open  l_cur for
   select id, status from tab where id = p_id; 
   p_Cursor := l_cur;
```

Two additional thinks come to mind.

You should rething the generall approach if the database is very dynamic. *How would you handle the case when other session deletes some row between the check and the second open of the cursor?*

Finally consider returning an exception instead of the return code.

Comment: So Either ways I must query once to find 1. If there is data ? and 2. If there is data get them. I was just curious if there is any way if i can achieve  this by querying once?

Comment: @radioactive001 I suppose you could copy the results into a temporary table. However it probably makes more sense for the caller to decide what to do with an empty result set.

Comment: AFAIK you **must fetch the first row** from the cursor to be able to check if it is empty. Anyway you may get rid of it by **slightly changing the contract of the interface**. Now the client must test the `error_msg` and if it is empty the cursor is processed. You may change it to *fetch the first row from cursor, if there is no row handle it as error, else process the cursor.*

Answer (score 1):

In order to know whether a cursor contains rows, you must open it and fetch the first row. Once you've done this, it makes no sense anymore to return that cursor, for the recipient will not be able to fetch that first row, because the cursor already points beyond it.

So, you must select twice. What you'd do is to use `ROWNUM` or an `EXISTS` clause here to show the DBMS that you are not interested in any more rows. This can speed up the query extremely.

```
PROCEDURE module_list_gk(p_module_id   IN   MODULE_LIST.MODULE_ID%TYPE,
                         p_error_code  OUT  NVARCHAR2,
                         p_error_msg   OUT  NVARCHAR2,
                         p_cursor      OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
  v_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO v_count
  FROM module_list
  WHERE module_id = p_module_Id
  AND ROWNUM = 1;

  IF v_count = 0 THEN
    p_error_code := 0; -- Or -1403 for NO DATA FOUND if you like
    p_error_msg := 'Does not Exists';
    RETURN;
  END IF;

  OPEN p_Cursor FOR
    SELECT module_id, module_nm, auth_status_id
    FROM module_list
    WHERE module_id = p_module_id;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  p_error_code:= SQLCODE;
  p_error_msg := SQLERRM;
END module_list_gk;
```

SQLCODE for the first query will be 0 by the way (`SELECT COUNT(*)` returns one row with the number of records found - no error hence). This is why you should decide to either return zero explicitly or some error code, such as -1403.

Here is the same with `EXISTS`:

```
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
  (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM module_list
    WHERE module_id = p_module_Id
  ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  INTO v_count
  FROM DUAL;

  IF v_count = 0 THEN
```